# Class not found although it's in an included file

Tags: php

In my main page (index.php) I've included "class_lib.php" which contains the class definitions.

When calling the class from index.php - I'm getting the followin

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'person' not found in /home/latingate/public_html/test/ObejectOriented/index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/latingate/public_html/test/ObejectOriented/index.php on line 5

What am I doing wrong?

index.php

```
<?php include("class_lib.php"); ?>

<?php

$stefan = new person();
$jimmy = new person;

$stefan->set_name("Stefan Mischook");
$jimmy->set_name("Nick Waddles");

echo "Stefan's full name: " . $stefan->get_name();
echo "Nick's full name: " . $jimmy->get_name();
?>
```

class_lib.php

```
<?php
class person {
    var $name;
    function set_name($new_name) {
        $this->name = $new_name;
    }

    function get_name() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
?>
```

you can see it online here:

[view online](http://galsarig.com/stackoverflow/ObejectOriented/index.php)

Comment: Can you provide a code for index.php and that included file? Not all is needed, just essential parts.

Comment: show `class_lib.php` File

Comment: it means your CLASS file path is not ok or there is class not available.

Comment: Use `require 'class_lib.php';` instead. It will fail if it cannot find the file. [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) doesn't fail, it just triggers a warning and if you suppressed the reporting of warning you don't even know when it fails.

Comment: I've provided the code of both files. see now above. thanks!

Comment: Is class_lib is in same directory ?

Comment: can u check this line $jimmy = new person; missed bractes

Comment: `var $name;`? This is PHP 4, which is dead and buried a decade ago. Read about [visibility of properties and methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). *Not related to your question, though.*

Comment: Yes. the included file is in the same directory

Comment: @istme Not using parentheses on instantiation of classes whose constructor doesn't have arguments is perfectly valid PHP code.

Comment: Problem solved. 
There was something wrong with uploading the included file.. not it's uploaded correctly.
Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and works for me.

I think Problems in file Path. So, first check your `class_lib.php` file is not in same directory then assign correct path.

Comment: this should be in comment . your reputation is good enough for write a comment

Comment: Problem solved. There was something wrong with uploading the included file.. not it's uploaded correctly. Thanks all